# Query on Naming in Python

Tags: python

When i say,

```
>>>radius = 2
```

Internally, a new object by name `radius` is created in `__main__` module's global frame and this object is of class `int`. Reference variable is also created by name `radius` which points to that object.

When i say,

```
>>>from math import sqrt
```

Internally, a new object by name `sqrt` is created in `__main__` module's global frame and this object is of class `function`. Reference variable is also created by name `sqrt` which points to that object of `function` type.

when i say,

```
>>>def square(x):
         return mul(x,x)
```

Internally, a new object by name `square` is created in `__main__` module's global frame and this object is of class `function`. Reference variable is also created by name `square` which points to that object of `function` type.

My question:

Is my understanding correct?

or

Does `radius` and `sqrt` and `square` objects are created outside `__main__` module's global frame and  reference variables(`radius` `sqrt` `square`) sitting within `__main__` module's global frame point to these objects?

In CS61A Fall 2012 course, the teacher says, this is how it is, which looks like hiding many details of python program memory model.

[image: program environment in memory]

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) and/or [this](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Comment: Objects don't have names, they only have references.So, saying *"a new object by name `radius` is created"* is wrong. Read: [A Word About Names and Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)

Comment: i just renamed 'space' to 'frame' in my query, as their are two frames, one global frame till the python program exits and local frame for every function call in python's program environment(memory).

Comment: No. This simply creates a *name* `radius` (not an object) which references the same `int` object referenced by the literal `2`.

Comment: @200OK: I believe calling them names is better than calling them references.  Since variables having immutable types are definitely not references.

Comment: @NeilG So, when do we think of references in python? i mean variables that point to modules/functions/class() objects are also `Names`? `not references`?

Comment: @NeilG i guess, pass-by-name is same as pass-by-value, creating another copy of the storage and assigning a new name to it.

Comment: @overexchange No, pass-by-name will never create another copy.  For mutable types, mutating operators in the function body can affect the object such that the change is reflected at all of its names.

Comment: @NeilG mutable types in the sense? any example?

Comment: You can for example write function that swaps two `list`s.

Comment: @NeilG so `li` is a reference here rather than `Name`? `li = ["a", "b", "mpilgrim", "z", "example"]`

Comment: I think it's both.  I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: @NeilG i think this is best example. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191966/references-in-python)

Comment: @slebetman In the below command, what are names and what are references? `>>> globals()
{'a': 4, 'b': 2, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> `

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of moot to ask where an object is created vs where a reference lives. As 200 OK points out in the comments, *all* object names are references - there is not a name which is more canonical or native than the rest. Objects simply exist (on a private heap, although that is for all intents and purposes irrelevant), and names point to them.

That said, there is one nuance that is not quite right in your question. When you import something from a module - whether it's the entire module itself, or just a function - a reference to that module is stored in the `sys.modules` dict. That ensures that when another part of the code imports from that module, it is not re-imported; the existing imported version is used.

Comment: Why do you call them references?  If you say `a = 2` then `b = a` it's not as if `b` is a reference to `a` nor is it a *reference* to the same object since `a += 2` has no effect on `b`.  Isn't it better to call them names?  The same object has two names.

Comment: i do not understand(picturize) sys.modules dictionary so i can't picturize yet how any simple python program will look in memory and point to other modules/functions when we try pointing it. Can you please picturize(in a diagram) any sample(simple) python program( in context to my query) that points to different module? That would make my life simpler.

Comment: @NeilG I'm not sure I understand your distinction. They are names which refer to things. You have to use some verb there: you could say they "point" to things, but pointer is an even more overloaded term than reference in this context.

Comment: @overexchange why do you care? Seriously? Python manages your memory for you; it is not C.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ya, coming from C, could be my problem of thinking internals of all segments of your process in memory.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so if my program is in multiple .py files, then dont you think i need to picturize things as i mentioned above?

Comment: No. Absolutely not. You import stuff and use it, that's all. How Python allocates the memory *is not your responsibility*. It might even change between Python versions, but you should not care.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Because unlike references in other languages, Python allows mutating operations on "immutable objects" so references doesn't fit.  Names is the most common terminology I've heard for Python.

Comment: @NeilG mutating operations on immutable objects? any example?

Comment: @overexchange: `b = 1` `b += 2`.  (Of course the first object is thrown away, but mentally, += seems to be mutating b.)

Comment: @NeilG In Python, for example,  * operator will  use .__mul__() or .__rmul__() methods of `int` class. so i think for `b=1` 1 is auto boxed to an object of class  `int` and some method(assignment) of that class `int` is invoked to perform assignment, b of thype `int` is used to invoke methods of that object. similarly b += 2 works. It is the object's method that performs any operation and b as reference is pointing to that object.

Comment: @overexchange:  I don't know what you're saying exactly.  In my example, __add__ is called and the result is assigned to b.  The point is that if it were a reference as in C++, __iadd__ would be called and all references would then have the new value.  (And just so it's clear no method of int is performing the assignment.)

Comment: @NeilG Oh you mean this? i think this is a strong point to not say references, when to say reference in python? >>> a=1
>>> b=a
>>> b
1
>>> a
1
>>> a += 2
>>> a
3
>>> b
1
>>>

Comment: @overexchange: Right, just like my first comment…

Comment: @NeilG So, when do we think of references in python? i mean variables that point to modules/functions/class() objects are also `Names`? `not references`?

Comment: @overexchange:  I don't know.  Maybe they're interchangeable.  But it's confusing since Python is pass-by-name rather than pass-by-reference.  That's also the reason you can't write a swap function easily.

Answer (score 0):

> Internally, a new object by name `radius` is created in `__main__` module's global frame and this object is of class `int`.

You are conflating object creation and binding (assignment) of references to objects. The statement `radius = 2` causes...

- evaluation of the expression `2`, which may or may not create an object (in CPython it doesn't because small integers are cached), then
- binding of the name `radius` to the object (value) that the evaluation produced.

Similarly, in the `import` case, the `import` may or may not create an object. If you imported `math` before, its objects are already created. You're just assigning a new name, `sqrt`, to an object that was created by importing the `math` module. Asking whether an object resides in a module or not makes no sense, because objects don't live in modules. They may be referenced by modules or created by imports, but afterward, they just in a single big, flat heap space. It's the references to them that form a structured namespace.

`def` is special in that it causes both evaluation and binding of a name to a function object.